# C++ reference syntax

Tags: c++

Which is the correct way to specify a reference. I know both works with the compiler, but wanted to know the correct way since I have seen both in  code bases.

```
void Subroutine(int &Parameter) 
{ 
    Parameter=100;
}
```

OR

```
void Subroutine(int& Parameter) 
{ 
    Parameter=100;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no 'correct' way, in the same way like there is no 'correct' way to place your parentheses and brackets. It's a matter of style and preference.

It's more important to be consistent.

Comment: ...but mine **is** the One True Style!

Comment: Andre, unfortunately there are lots of people who say that and actually mean it :)

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to pointers, C programmers tend to write `int *i` which reads "evaluating `*i` yields an `int`". This is not possible with references. If you write `int &i`, evaluating `&i` does *not* yield an int, but rather a pointer to an int, because `&` has different meanings in declarations and expressions.

That's why I prefer to declare reference variables as `int& i`, because `i` is a reference to an int.

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of preference, both are correct, personally I nowadays like to write it as type&

Answer (score 1):

I think the two are functionally identical. I personally prefer int& Parameter since it makes more sense to me -- i.e. a variable named `Parameter` is of type `reference-to-int`, whereas int &Parameter doesn't immediately make that connection to me. Most examples I've seen use the int& form as well. (i.e. see http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's code style issue, no one is good or bad, correct or wrong.
I use this:

int & a;
int * b;

Too many spaces (any maybe a little confusing with binary operator & and *) but it looks clear to me.

As long as consistent, whatever your style is correct.