# Where to place the '&' in a parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between

```
void fun(MyClass &mc);
```

and

```
void fun(MyClass& mc);
```

in C++?

Comment: I'm sure this is explained in most introductory material.

Comment: I had to read this question 3 times in order to realize that this is a syntax question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ reference syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515306/c-reference-syntax)

Comment: @Layne: It's not a syntax question, merely an aesthetic question. White space is irrelevant to syntax.

Comment: why so many downvoters? the question is not bad at all. gosh I hate people doing that

Comment: I posted this question just to post something in a new community I joined. Hence the quality of the question was initialy very bad which earned earned all the negative votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As given none.

Originally, C would allow:

```
int x, *y;
```

To declare both an `int`, `x` and a pointer to int, `y`.

Hence part of the definition of the type - the bit that makes it a pointer - could be separated from another part.

C++ copied this wholesale.

Then references where added, and they got a similar style of declaration except with `&` rather than `*`. This meant that both `MyClass &mc` and `MyClass& mc` were allowed.

On the choice when it comes to `*`, Strousup [wrote](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace):

> Both are "right" in the sense that
>   both are valid C and C++ and both have
>   exactly the same meaning. As far as
>   the language definitions and the
>   compilers are concerned we could just
>   as well say "int*p;" or "int * p;"
>
> The choice between "int* p;" and "int
>   *p;" is not about right and wrong, but about style and emphasis. C emphasized
>   expressions; declarations were often
>   considered little more than a
>   necessary evil. C++, on the other
>   hand, has a heavy emphasis on types.
>
> A "typical C programmer" writes "int
>   *p;" and explains it "*p is what is the int" emphasizing syntax, and may
>   point to the C (and C++) declaration
>   grammar to argue for the correctness
>   of the style. Indeed, the * binds to
>   the name p in the grammar.
>
> A "typical C++ programmer" writes
>   "int* p;" and explains it "p is a
>   pointer to an int" emphasizing type.
>   Indeed the type of p is int*. I
>   clearly prefer that emphasis and see
>   it as important for using the more
>   advanced parts of C++ well.
>
> The critical confusion comes (only)
>   when people try to declare several
>   pointers with a single declaration:
>
> int* p, p1; // probable error: p1 is
>   not an int*
>
> Placing the * closer to the name does
>   not make this kind of error
>   significantly less likely.
>
> int *p, p1; // probable error?
>
> Declaring one name per declaration
>   minimizes the problem - in particular
>   when we initialize the variables.
>   People are far less likely to write:
>
> int* p = &i;    int p1 = p; // error:
>   int initialized by int*
>
> And if they do, the compiler will
>   complain.
>
> Whenever something can be done in two
>   ways, someone will be confused.
>   Whenever something is a matter of
>   taste, discussions can drag on
>   forever. Stick to one pointer per
>   declaration and always initialize
>   variables and the source of confusion
>   disappears. See The Design and
>   Evolution of C++ for a longer
>   discussion of the C declaration
>   syntax.

By extension, when it comes to `&`, `MyClass& mc` matches the "typical C++" style.

Answer (score 5):

To the compiler there's no difference.

The first is closer to usual C-syntax, the latter is more C++-ish.